# Relation between VOT and three way distinctions between plosives and affricates

Tags: affricates, plosives

I faced this puzzling Fill in the Blank which asks-
VOT can make a three way differentiation among i.____________________ ii. ________________________ iii. _____________________plosives and fricatives....

Comment: Do you mean, this is a homework question and you don't understand it, or you don't know the answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer. And I don't understand whether it will be acoustic properties, or in the line of voiceless aspirated, or unaspirated.... it is really unclear.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want i: voiced (negative onset time), ii: tenuis (voiceless unaspirated, or no  onset time), iii: aspirated (voiceless aspirated, or positive onset time).